# How can I retrieve the total number of documents indexed by Lucene in 3.0.2?

Tags: java, lucene, indexing

I'm searching through some documents, and I'd like to return the amount of matching documents  against the amount of documents indexed.

Answer (score 3):

You could create a [MatchAllDocsQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_0/api/org/apache/lucene/search/MatchAllDocsQuery.html) which according to the javadocs states:

> A query that matches all documents.

Otherwise perhaps the [IndexReader](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_0/api/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexReader.html#numDocs%28%29) might be useful:

```
IndexReader.open("path/to/index").numDocs();
```

Comment: As far as I know from the Javadocs, IndexReader supports only open(directory) from ".open" in 3.0.2. I haven't tried using MatchAllDocsQuery yet.